# How do I resume a performSelector method after being paused?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, resume

I've looked around on stack overflow for days and have not seen an answer to my problem.  I have several methods in my main game scene that are called by

```
[self performSelector:@selector(MethodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
```

When I leave the game and come back, it looks like all of my methods run at once.  I assume this is because the delay time is calculating in the background, but I do not understand how to correct this in cocos2d.  I thought I didn't need to deal with NSTimers with the pause/resume functions in cocos2d?  What simple piece of information am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cocos-2d schedulers to solve this problem. See the below code:

```
 [className schedule: @selector(selectorName) interval:2];
```

When you pause the game using :   `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];` this timer's will paused. And when you resume the game using : `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];` It will also resume.

Comment: So instead of performSelector, I need to use schedule: in its place and then unschedule the method once it runs since it only needs to run one time?

Comment: You must unschedule it by : [self unscheduleAllSelectors];

Comment: Awesome!  I was worried that the structure of my app was completely wrong!  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create sequence of actions to make delayed single method call.

```
id delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: yourDuration];
id call = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:yourTarget selector:yourSelector];
id sequence = [CCSequence methodOne: delay two: call];
[someNode runAction:sequence];
```